# Python PostgreSQL "error insert has more target columns than expressions" but its not

Tags: python, postgresql

Im new to SQL and PostgreSQL and I cant understand whats going on with this code.

Im trying to insert csv to postgres with this code:

```
import csv
import psycopg2 as pg
filename = 'myfile.csv'
try:
    conn = pg.connect(user="myuser",
        password="mypass",
        host="myhost",
        port="5432",
        database="mydb")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader) # This skips the 1st row which is the header.
        for record in reader:
            print(record)
            cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO auth VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", record)
            conn.commit()
except (Exception, pg.Error) as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    if (conn):
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        print("Connection closed.")
```

but it raise **error insert has more target columns than expressions
LINE 1: ...00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '1580463062', 'auto')**

but here is what i want to insert
['00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '1580463062', 'auto'] 
and its look like its definitely has exactly 4 colums

I also tried to change the encoding of csv from ASCII to UTF-8 and UTF-8_SIG but i still get this error

Comment: """INSERT INTO....)""", (record[0], record[1],record[2],record[3]))

Comment: cursor.execute() takes at most 2 arguments. 
But i also tried **cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO auth VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {})""".format(record[0], record[1],record[2],record[3])** and i still get this error

Comment: sorry gotta wrap the records in parenthesis, check the documentation https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html

Comment: @Chris and still that doesnt work, i even tried to make it like this **...VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '1580463062', 'auto')** but get this error. 
I have 4 text columns in my table in postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with this code

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=host dbname=dbname user=user 
password=password")
cur = conn.cursor()
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    cur.copy_from(f, 'auth', sep=',')

conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```